# How to fully revert Python to factory settings on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I was looking for this information for a while, but as additional packages and python versions can be installed through `homebrew` and `pip` I have the feeling that my environment is messed up. Furthermore a long time ago, I had installed some stuff with `sudo pip install` and as well `sudo python ~/get-pip.py`.

Is there a trivial way of removing all danging dependencies and have python as it was when I first got the machine, or at least with only the packages that are delivered with the Mac distro?

Comment: [Try this May help, Remove and Reinstall Python on Mac — Can I trust these old references?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284824/remove-and-reinstall-python-on-mac-can-i-trust-these-old-references)

Comment: As far as I am aware there are no extra packages installed with MacOS. By default the system python will have site packages in `/Library/Python/<Version>/site-packages`. But I would be surprised if you have installed into this, user installed versions would normally be in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/<version>/...`. If you installed anything via `homebrew` you can completely nuke that. Good luck in getting your system back into a good state - I would learn how to use virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

For the system modules you installed via `pip`, I would do a:

```
sudo pip freeze > system_modules.txt
sudo pip uninstall -y -r system_modules.txt
```

If you also did the same as a user, I would do the same without `sudo` (and changing the filename)

For `homebrew`, you can try remove python and just install it again:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python3
```

I recommend you to install [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) as soon as you reinstall python
then you can just create a new virtual environment:

```
virtualenv new_env
```

activate it:

```
source new_env/bin/activate
```

and work there, and if at some point you mess up some packages, you can just remove the directory.
After the activation you will be able to `pip install` any package and it will remain inside `new_env`.

Answer (score 0):

first delete directories where python is installed. you can find these using

$ which python

$ which python3

then use 
$ brew doctor

you will find broken links which can be removed using  --> $ brew prune

finally, you should reinstall python using homebrew

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

instead of 'brew prune' its 'brew cleanup'. prune might be an old command.